# Django annotate cannot access model's floatfield

Tags: python, django, string, floating-point

I am trying annotate a queryset with the object's distance from a user's provided location. Here is what I have so far:

```
lat1 = request.POST['lat']
lon1 = request.POST['lon']

locations = Location.objects.annotate(distance_away = posDifference('lat', 'lon', lat1, lon1)).order_by('distance_away')[0]
```

Here is the `posDifference` function, it returns the distance between the two points in miles.

```
def posDifference(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):

    EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3958.761

    lat1 = float(lat1)
    lon1 = float(lon1)
    lat2 = float(lat2)
    lon2 = float(lon2)

    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)

    delta_lon = radians(lon1 - lon2)
    cos_x = (sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(delta_lon)) # Distance formula
    distance = acos(cos_x) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES # Conversion to miles

    return distance
```

The error I am getting is `ValueError: could not convert string to float: lat` at line `lat1 = float(lat1)` in `posDifference`. I believe the strings`'lat'` and `'lon'` are being passed to the function instead of the Location object's fields `lat` and `lon`.

Comment: Post the full traceback so we can see where the error originates. You probably also need to post the code for either the location model, the definition of `posDifference`, or both.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here. `annotate` does a calculation in the database, but presumably `posDifference` is a Python function.

Comment: I have clarified further and provided the code for `posDifference`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are just passed into function. You're simply calling `posDifference` with that parameters. I'm not sure why are you expecting other result...

You should build your function in different way, using `F` for referring to correct db column and `Func` for referring to some SQL functions (`sin`, `cos`, `acos`). It can look like this:

```
from django.db.models import Func, F

# It's better to build some library of used database functions first:
class Radians(Func):
    function = 'RADIANS'

class Sin(Func):
    function = 'SIN'

class Cos(Func):
    function = 'COS'

class Acos(Func):
    function = 'ACOS'

def posDifference(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):

    EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3958.761

    lat1 = F(lat1)
    lon1 = F(lon1)
    lat2 = float(lat2)
    lon2 = float(lon2)

    lat1 = Radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)

    delta_lon = Radians(lon1) - radians(lon2)
    cos_x = (Sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + Cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * Cos(delta_lon)) # Distance formula
    distance = Acos(cos_x) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES # Conversion to miles

    return distance
```

That should work fine. More on that you can learn from [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/)

Answer (score 0):

You sholud better use [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/) for that measurements. There are ready for use functions for calculating distances, comparing distances, checking if point on map is inside some range or rectangle etc. All is done on database level and requires only some database extension.